# Binding a mutltiple parent hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, hierarchy, recursive-query, dimensional

I have a table where informantion about some branches and hierarchies are kept. The information are not in stored in a way that can be used in dimensional modelling, so after many transformations and extractation I end up with this:

[image: Hierarchy]

where  n0 it's the first level and the n11 ist the highest level. 
The problem is that the hierarchy cannot be travers like this:

```
SELECT 
    distinct 
        nelem.Element n0,
        primul.Element n1,
        doilea.Element n2, 
        treilea.Element n3,
        patrulea.Element n4 

FROM 
    [MIS].[dbo].[BedrockImportBST] nelem
    left join  [BedrockImportBST] primul on primul.Element=nelem.Value1 and primul.LineType in ('e','p')
    left join  [BedrockImportBST] doilea on doilea.Element=primul.Value1 and doilea.LineType in ('e','p')
    left join  [BedrockImportBST] treilea on treilea.Element=doilea.Value1 and treilea.LineType in ('e','p')
    left join  [BedrockImportBST] patrulea on patrulea.Element=treilea.Value1 and patrulea.LineType in ('e','p')
```

Is there a posibility to assign parent-child realtionship ids to  this solution so that the traversing would be recursiv?

Comment: As long as the number of levels in your hierarchy is fixed and you also have IDs for each of those levels, not just the labels I see in your screenshot, you can build a flattened dimension having separate attributes for each level. Under normal conditions, the flat hierarchy will perform better than a parent-child hierarchy in SSAS. But what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Salut George, voi continua in engleza pentru a intelege si restul daca vor avea nevoie. I don't have any ids just the labels , and I want to generate a view structured as  ID, Parent_Id, Name... As you  can see in the first pritnscreen , 047 can have many hierarchy paths ( Ex: 047/ Inland (100%) / Konzern (100%) / Alle BST-Elemente  si 047 / Inland (ant.) / Europa (ant.) / Welt (ant.) / Alle BST-Elemente )

Comment: @GeorgeTanasie I am thinking maybe at a cte  or a while to travers ...from right to left, where  Alle BST-Elemente will be the highest level and 047 will be the lowest element , but i cannot figure it out how can i build it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just for transforming the flat data into a parent-child hierarchy, you could generate unique IDs with simple unions like below (I used FlatHierarchy as the name of your table). I see that a specific element can appear on multiple levels and can have different parents, which seems a bit strange, but here it goes:

```
DECLARE @IDS TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    Label varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO @IDS (Label)
SELECT n0
FROM FlatHierarchy
UNION 
SELECT n1
FROM FlatHierarchy
UNION 
SELECT n2
FROM FlatHierarchy
UNION 
SELECT n3
FROM FlatHierarchy
UNION 
SELECT n4
FROM FlatHierarchy
UNION 
SELECT n5
FROM FlatHierarchy
.....
UNION 
SELECT n11
FROM FlatHierarchy


SELECT i.ID, parent.ID ParentID, i.Label
FROM @IDS i
INNER JOIN FlatHierarchy f ON i.Label = f.n0
LEFT JOIN @IDS parent ON f.n1 = parent.Label
UNION 
SELECT i.ID, parent.ID ParentID, i.Label
FROM @IDS i
INNER JOIN FlatHierarchy f ON i.Label = f.n1
LEFT JOIN @IDS parent ON f.n2 = parent.Label
UNION 
SELECT i.ID, parent.ID ParentID, i.Label
FROM @IDS i
INNER JOIN FlatHierarchy f ON i.Label = f.n2
LEFT JOIN @IDS parent ON f.n3 = parent.Label
UNION 
SELECT i.ID, parent.ID ParentID, i.Label
FROM @IDS i
INNER JOIN FlatHierarchy f ON i.Label = f.n3
LEFT JOIN @IDS parent ON f.n4 = parent.Label
UNION 
SELECT i.ID, parent.ID ParentID, i.Label
FROM @IDS i
INNER JOIN FlatHierarchy f ON i.Label = f.n4
LEFT JOIN @IDS parent ON f.n5 = parent.Label
.....
UNION 
SELECT i.ID, parent.ID ParentID, i.Label
FROM @IDS i
INNER JOIN FlatHierarchy f ON i.Label = f.n10
LEFT JOIN @IDS parent ON f.n11 = parent.Label
```